# UICollectionView – get notified of a tap in an area where there is no cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

For when the user hits a `UICollectionView` cell, one can just implement the appropriate delegate method, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

Is there a way to also get notified when the user taps anywhere else in the collection view (even if there is no cell there)?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add and image view and on top of add a UIButton with action witch will handle the event apart from cell, i guess this is the way you can get the solution...

Comment: Can you clarify please? Why would I be adding an image view anywhere? I don't think this answers the question

Comment: I am thinking like as image View can be subview of collection view, so you also can make subview the UIButton and add to collectionview which will be able to respond your action of touch other then cell